# cscart product minimum quantity issue

Tags: store, product, cs-cart, quantify

So here is my problem, I'm setting up CsCart V3.0  for an online store and on the product page Minimum Quantity field displays the entire product name and then minimum quantity, example below.

Minimum quantity for "Edimax EW-7811Un Network adapter - Hi-Speed USB" is 1.

I don't need product name to be displayed in Minimum Quantity since customer already on the product page. Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by two ways, but first of all, for what do you need such configuration? It is illogical. 1 is a minimal required value. You will not be able to add 0 products.

Any way:

1) Change the language variable. Go to the Administration -> Languages (in your backend). Find "Minimum quantity for" using the search. You will see something like this:
[image: Language variables]

Change the value to any text you need (For example: "Minimum quantity is [quantity]")

2) Open this file: **stores/[YOUR_STORE_ID]/skins/[YOUR_SKIN]/customer/common_templates/product_data.tpl**

And find this code:

```
{capture name="min_qty_`$obj_id`"}
{if $min_qty && $product.min_qty}
    <p class="description">{$lang.text_cart_min_qty|replace:"[product]":$product.product|replace:"[quantity]":$product.min_qty}.</p>
{/if}
{/capture}
```

You can change the language variable to your or change this code as you wish.